# Rollup pack scss into multiple bundles

Tags: sass, svelte, rollupjs, svelte-3, rollup-plugin-postcss

I am using rollup-plugin-scs([v3.0.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-scss)) plugin in rollup(v2.62.0) to pack my svelte(v3.44.3) application.

There are two sets of scss files. One set is for left-to-right languages, and the other for right-to-left languages. For each set, there is an entry scss file, which imports other relevant scss files.

**What I am expecting**, is to pack the scss files into two individual bundles.

- src/styles/global_ltr.scss => global_ltr.css
- src/styles/global_rtl.scss => global_rtl.css

Then my svelte component can load corresponding css file lazily according to the visitor's language.

```html
<svelte:head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/global_ltr.css" />  // or global_rlt.css if Hebrew
</svelte:head>
```

`rollup.config.js` looks like as below

```js
import scss from 'rollup-plugin-scss'
import sveltePreprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';

// ...

{
        input: [ /*...*/ ],
        output: {
            sourcemap: true,
            format: 'amd',
            name: 'app',
            dir: destDir
        },
        plugins: [
            scss({
                include: [ './src/styles/global_ltr.scss', './src/styles/global_rtl.scss'],
                output: function (styles, styleNodes) {
                    console.log(styleNodes);
                    fs.writeFileSync(destDir + 'global_ltr.css', styles)
                },
                failOnError: true,
            }),

            svelte({
                preprocess: sveltePreprocess(),
                emitCss: false, // <style> in components are not included in bundles
            }),


            // ...
        ]
}
```

**What issues I am encountering**:

1. Two sets are bundled into a single one.  The `scss({output: function})` callback is only fired once with both l-t-r and r-t-l styles.
2. I have to import both entry scss files in my application otherwise they won't be bundled.

```
import 'styles/global_ltr.scss';
import 'styles/global_rtl.scss';
```

In general, I am trying to bundle two sets of scss files into two individual css files without considering svelte.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 0):

styleNodes according to package is types is:

```
export interface IdAndContentObject {
    id?: string;
    content?: string;
}
styleNodes: IdAndContentObject[]
```

that array, In this case you can try with id of and content(all css files convert to string) use them